# Getting Error whenever try to logged In classic mode

Tags: salesforce-classic, login-errors

[image]

Getting Error whenever try to logged In classic mode

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! For this, you'll need to contact support. There's nothing we can do to help you here. While some salesforce.com employees do visit here, this isn't an official support channel for things like this. That said, when you get a response from support, you can post that response here, as it may help someone else solve the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seem to be related to [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002KbSNQA0) and as per my understanding we see this issue only in certain org,  Can you try removing the trailing URI(/home.JSP) and switch to lightning experience.

Pls provide me with org Id, if you still see this issue.

Thanks